# Replace values in a pandas column that satisfy some condition leads to SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Let `dtrain` be of type `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

What is the right way to do the following?

```
target = dtrain.iloc[:,1] > 0
dtrain.ix[target, 1] = 0
```

I get the warning:

> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:477:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>       A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>       Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Note:
Earlier I create `dtrain` using

```
dtrain = d.loc[(d.yyyy < 2005) & (d.yyyy >= 1995),:]
```

This might be a n00b question. I'm reasonably new to Python and don't have a good model in my head yet of what triggers a deep copy and what's just a pointer...

Comment: I think need `copy` - `dtrain = d.loc[(d.yyyy < 2005) & (d.yyyy >= 1995),:].copy()`

Comment: @jezrael THANKS! That works. Lol... should I just delete this question because it's too trivial?

Comment: I find some simplify your code, but it is up to you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first can simplify code from:

```
dtrain = d.loc[(d.yyyy < 2005) & (d.yyyy >= 1995),:]
```

to:

```
dtrain = d[(d.yyyy < 2005) & (d.yyyy >= 1995)]
```

it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

and then add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) - [see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#copying).

```
dtrain = d[(d.yyyy < 2005) & (d.yyyy >= 1995)].copy()
```